# How to share a website on FB by URL

Tags: facebook

I want to share a website on FB(social button idea), but as this is an basic button I dont want to use any kind of script so how can I share a site on FB by clicking on a link?

Yes I dont want to show a popup and not a new tab!

//example

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com?share=www.mysite.com">share on facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the sharer.php for this:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.devils-heaven.com

No script or App needed. You can also invoke the Share Dialog, but you do need an App ID for that (see "URL Redirection"): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog